# Syntax error in creating Trigger in mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

m writing following lines for creating a trigger:

```
create trigger notify after insert on applications
for each row
begin
insert into notifications SET sno=1;
end;
```

but everytime i get following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4

line 4 is - `insert into notifications SET sno=1`

Comment: Well, the `INSERT` query is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is confused about the delimiters. It thinks the first `;` is the end of the `TRIGGER` declaration (which it is not). Use `delimiter` to change it temporarily, and later to change it back:

```
delimiter |
create trigger notify after insert on applications
for each row
begin
insert into notifications (sno) values (1);
end;
|
delimiter ;
```

More in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-trigger.html).